# Trying to get the columns by passing database name and schema and tablename

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the code to get the column names from a SQL Server table, but I want to pass the database name and schema and table name to get the columns.

I tried using `information_schema` and many other ways like using system base tables but none is close to what I am trying.

I am checking for this:

```
select column_name 
from mydatabase.schema.tablename
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the information you want is stored in the `sys` objects, and some in the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` objects (the latter are more for compatibility as they do not cover all of the information of objects in SQL Server). *Apparently*, as well, the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` objects *can* report the incorrect value for the object's schema, however, that has been a point myself and several others have contested with the documentation authors for some time.

Anyway, if we *assume* we're still using `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` parametrising the table and schema is simple:

```sql
DECLARE @schema sysname,
        @table sysname;
SET @schema = N'dbo';
SET @table = N'mytable';
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = @schema
  AND TABLE_NAME = @table;'
```

Parametrising the database is a little different. The data in the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` (and `sys`) objects is relevant to the database you are **currently** connected to. You can use 3 part naming, for example `mydatabase.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`, however, you cannot parametrise an objects name. Something like `@database.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` won't work.

You therefore need to use a dynamic statement here:

```sql
DECLARE @database sysname,
        @schema sysname,
        @table sysname;
SET @database = N'mydatabase';
SET @schema = N'dbo';
SET @table = N'mytable';

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);
SET @SQL = N'SELECT *
FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@database) + N'.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = @schema
  AND TABLE_NAME = @table;';

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL, N'@schema sysname, @table sysname', @schema, @table;
```

---

As noted, the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` objects aren't complete for SQL Server, and they do have the schema caveat. Personally I prefer using the `sys` objects. For a non-dynamic query that would be the following to get the table's column names:

```sql
SELECT c.[name] AS ColumnName
FROM sys.schemas s
     JOIN sys.tables t ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
     JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
WHERE s.[name] = @schema
  AND t.[name] = @table;
```

Comment: found a solution using the  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS

Comment: If you found an answer that was different to my own, @Asum , you should post an answer. Answering your own questions isn't a problem, and is actually encouraged. If you found another question that answered the question, you can flag your own question as a duplicate of that question.